# SignalR Core Giving ConnectionId Required Error

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm trying to implement SignalR in my ASP.NET Core 2.0 app -- using SignalR Core Alpha.

[image]

When I use Postman to send a simple text to the Hub, I'm getting `HttpStatus` `400` with `ConnectionId Required` error message. In Postman, I tried both `GET` and `POST` methods and got the same result.

[image]

[image]

I have a very simple method that receives a string -- see below:

```
public Task Send(string message)
{
   return Clients.All.InvokeAsync("Send", message);
}
```

Any idea what's wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got a response from the man himself @DavidFowl on Twitter that I must send my messages through the SignalR client for the hub to accept them. SignalR hub won't accept messages from a regular web client.
https://twitter.com/SamUresin/status/944652532990738433