# ASP.NET Core Web Api and SignalR over CORS

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, cors, signalr, .net-6.0

I'm developing a ASP.NET Core Web API .NET6 on visual studio, I added SignalR and CORS to it. If I open the SignalR URL on a browser I do see the "Connection ID required"

Now I created a html webpage with Visual Studio Code and its Live Server and ty to connect to the SignalR hub using the URL I see in the browser when starting my ASP.NET Core web api.

It cannot connect, no matter what I get

```
A cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) request was blocked because
it was configured to include credentials and the Access-Control-Allow-Origin
response header of the request or the associated preflight request was set to a wildcard *.
CORS requests may only include credentials for resources where
the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is not a wildcard.
```

This is my full Program.cs

```
using VikingServer.Hubs;

var MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                      builder =>
                      { 
                          builder.AllowCredentials(); 
                          // also tried builder.AllowAnyOrigen();
                      });
});
builder.Services.AddSignalR();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);

app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello world");
app.MapHub<GameHub>("/GameHub");


app.Run();
```

And the client side on JS:

```
const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl("https://localhost:7067/gamehub")       
         //The url is correct since I have different behavior 
         //when the server is not running on VS
    .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
    .build();

async function start() {
    try {
        await connection.start();
        console.log("SignalR Connected.");
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        //setTimeout(start, 5000);
    }
};

connection.onclose(async () => {
    await start();
});

// Start the connection.
start();
```

The server side will eventually run on heroku and the client side on some cheap web host such as 000WebHost.. In case some of this might affect the best solution to the problem

Comment: Read the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/signalr/security?view=aspnetcore-6.0#cross-origin-resource-sharing

Comment: `"Connection ID required"`,about the error you can referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47955366/signalr-core-giving-connectionid-required-error).If you try to use builder.AllowAnyOrigen()..AllowCredentials(),will it be solved?

Comment: Nop as stated in the comment in the doce the AllowAnyOrigen wastested and did not work. I also tried the AllowCredentias,, does not work either